# How is my computer able to resolve hostnames on my subnet not registered to DNS?

Tags: networking, dns

I just deployed Canonical Landscape on a virtual machine on my network.

When i entered the IPv4 address of the virtual machine in my browser to get started, it redirected me to the hostname of the virtual machine, 'vm-17'.

```
Location: https://vm-17:443/
```

This is fine, and there is nothing malfunctioning, but it made me wonder how this works.

How is my computer able to resolve this hostname, even though nslookup returns nothing, and there is no A record on my DNS server? I presume there is some other protocol than DNS making this work? The target machine resides in the same subnet as my computer.

```
C:\Users\bob>nslookup vm-17
Server:  VHOST-03.alice.local
Address:  192.168.223.9

*** VHOST-03.alice.local can't find vm-17: Non-existent domain

C:\Users\bob>ping vm-17

Pinging vm-17.local [192.168.223.27] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.223.27: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Comment: Your computer broadcasts its hostname in order to allow devices to ping it as long as its in the same network without requiring it to be registered through a DNS service. This is inherited from the time when there were no DNS servers present in the network by default. Not entirely sure if its a feature of netbios though but I think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's using Multicast DNS (mDNS), which is part of the IETF ZeroConf suite of protocols. It's a standardized version of Apple's Bonjour, and is now widely supported in Linux distros including Android, and in Windows 10.

There are a few different open source packages for Linux that implement mDNS. The one that's probably been most widely deployed and is most well known is called Avahi.

The `nslookup`, `dig`, and `host` tools each contain their own unicast-only DNS resolver code and don't use the OS's DNS resolver library, so they are blind to mDNS.

`ping` (and anything else that's not specifically a DNS-debugging tool) will use the system's DNS resolver, so on a system with Avahi installed and running, it will make use of mDNS without you having to do anything special.

Please note that the IETF has reserved `.local` for use with mDNS. If you want to use a pseudo-TLD for unicast DNS on your local network, you should probably use `.test` so that you do not conflict with mDNS.

Comment: Yeah that makes sence, thanks! Very cool stuff. Do you happen to know which implementation of mDNS windows is using? I have disabled LMHOSTS and NetBIOS.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the reserved TLD by the way. I'll get to changing that asap.